# Use superposition to find voltage V1

Tags: voltage, current, ac, phasor, superposition

[image]

I  first open circuited the 50 mA source and used Ohm's law to find \$V_1\$
$$V_1= 20 ∠0°  \frac{j50 \times (-j25+40)}{j25 +40}$$
but the answer is not correct. Also, how do I find \$V_1\$ when the 20 mA source is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) The circuit across the active current source is a parallel circuit of C and a series circuit of R and L.

1. Note that components values are given as **admittances** (not as impedances).
   So you can't calculate \$V = IZ\$ (\$Z=\$impedance) but
   you have to use \$V = \frac{I}{Y}\$ (\$Y=\$admittance).
2. The total admittance is \$Y=Y_C + Y_{RL}\$ (parallel admittance are calculated like series impedances or resistances: just add them) and
3. \$Y_{RL}=\frac{Y_R Y_{L}}{Y_R + Y_{L}}\$ (series admittance are calculated like parallel impedances or resistances: product divided by sum)

If you follow the steps you get exactly the given solution.

(b) Now the circuit across the active current source is a parallel circuit of L and a series circuit of R and C.

You get V1 by

1. using the current divider formula to get \$I_L\$ and \$I_{RC}\$
2. \$V1 = \frac{I_C}{Y_C}\$ where \$I_C = I_{RC}\$ (because R and C are in series).